# How much data will be transferred from memory to CPU in a single call

Tags: hardware, cpu-architecture

As memory is much slower to CPU, It should send the data in blocks of some 'x'Bytes.

1. How much would be the size of this 'x'?
2. Do the data line b/n memory and CPU is also a x*8 bit lane?
3. If I access an address 'A' on memory, would it be sending all the next x-1 memory addresses to the cache?
4. What is the Approx frequency a memory bus would be working?
5. SIMD - Do SSE and MMX extensions somehow leverage this bulk reading feature?

Please feel free to provide any references.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The size 'x' is generally the size of a cache line. Cache line size depends on the architecture, but Intel and AMD use 64 byte.
2. At least . If you have more channels, you can fetch more data from different channels.
3. Not exactly the next x-1 memory addresses. You can think of the memory, divided into 64 byte chunks. Every time you want to access even one byte, you will bring the chunk your address belongs. Lets assume you want to access the address 123 (decimal). The start of the address should be 64 to 127. So, you will bring that whole chunk. Which means, you do not only bring the following ones, but the previous addresses as well, depending on the address you access of course.
4. That depends the version of DDR you CPU supports. You can check some numbers in here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_data_rate
5. Yes, they do. When you bring a data from memory to caches, you bring one cache line, and SIMD extensions work on multiple data elements in a single instruction. Which means if you want to add 4 values in one instruction, the data you are looking for would be in the cache (since you brought the whole chunk) and you just read it from cache.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ParallelHighway. Do you know any  good resource where I can get this info of modern CPUs?

Comment: There is a lot of information for many generations of CPUs in here [link](http://www.agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf). You may want to check the parts related with cache and memory accesses.